# Standard topology doesn't match with the topology induced by the p-adic metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, p-adic-number-theory

I want to show that the standard topology on $\Bbb Q$ doesn't match with the topology that is induced by the p-adic metric. For this I wanna show that for the open set $M:= \{x \in \Bbb Q: |x|_p <\frac{1}{p}\}$ there exist no ball set in the standard topology with only these elements. I know that in $M$ there are only elements that are divisible by $p^2$  in the counter. But now I am stucked....

Comment: Are you trying to prove that $M$ is not a ball with respect to the standard topology?

Comment: Yes, this I wanna prove

Comment: Why? In $\Bbb R^2$, if $d_1\bigl((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)\bigr)=|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|$ and $d_2\bigl((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)\bigr)=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}$, then $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent, but no open ball with respect to one of them is also an open ball with respect to the other one.

Comment: Why are you suddenly in $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: It was an example that shows that your approach is wrong.

Comment: When metrics induce the same topology, open balls in one must be open *sets* in the other. But they do not have to be *balls* in the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\Bbb Q$ with the $p$-adic metric, $\lim_{n\to\infty}p^n=0$, but not in $\Bbb Q$ with the usual metric.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you pls explain a bit more your answer?

Comment: If two distance are equivalent, then a sequence is convergent with respect to one of them if and only if it is convergent with respect to the other one.

Answer (score 2):

To work with your set $M=\{x \in \mathbb Q: \lvert x\rvert_p < 1/p \}$, let's just see that it's not open with respect to the standard topology of $\mathbb Q$ (and that is what you have to show: as explained in the comments, it does not suffice to show that it's not a ball in the standard metric).

Well $0 \in M$ and so for $M$ to be open in the standard topology, there must be some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $M$ contains $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \cap \mathbb Q$. But now choose $n$ big enough so that (for example)  $x:= \frac{1}{(p+1)^n} < \varepsilon$. Then $x \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \cap \mathbb Q$ but $x \notin M$, contradiction, so $M$ is not open in the standard topology.